# How do I get HTML tags inside of a Javascript Text Node?

Tags: javascript, html, text, tags

my question was pretty much explained up in the title. How do I get HTML tags inside of a Javascript Text Node? The result of my code on the page is...

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Click Here</a>
```

However, I want "Click Here" to be a link. I am new to Javascript, so this would help me out a lot. Below is an example of what I'm talking about...

```
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mynode=document.createTextNode('<a href="http://www.example.com">Click Here</a>');
document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(mynode);
</script>
```

Comment: Just to convince you that jQuery is worth checking out... this is incredibly easy with jQuery (or similar libraries): `$('#mydiv').append('<a href="...">...</a>');` – as Quentin's answer shows, it's quite a bit more complicated with plain DOM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't put links in a text node. Links are elements. Elements can (sometimes) contain text nodes, but the reverse is not true.

You need to create an element, set attributes on it, then append text to that element.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.example.com');
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Click Here'));
document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Wow, this was my first question on Stack Overflow and I got a great answer super fast. I guess this is goodbye to Yahoo Answers...

Comment: Given that the OP is new to JavaScript, I'd encourage using the `href` property rather than `setAttribute()`, which is broken in older IE and almost always unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="mydiv">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute("href","http://www.example.com");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Click Here'));
    document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(element); </script>

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that you're *absolutely* okay to post answers to answered questions; but please consider taking a read of the [mark-down editing pages](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to show code in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `document.createElement`, not `document.createTextNode`. Text-nodes cannot contain HTML.

An easy alternative, if you're not using complex Javascript (which it seems you aren't) would just be:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML.='<a href="http://www.example.com">Click Here</a>';
```

Comment: Modifying innerHTML is risky because it will likely break all event handlers tied to existing child elements of 'mydiv'.

Comment: Or `.innerHTML += ...` given that the OP was trying to append. (And bearing in mind what Jan said.)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to insert an element in the middle of a text node (replace a word with a span). I did it by replacing the text node altogether:

(uses jQuery)

```
function replace_text(element, search, replacement_html){
  if(!element) element=document.body;
  var nodes=element.childNodes;
  for(var n=0;n<nodes.length;n++){
    if(nodes[n].nodeType==Node.TEXT_NODE){
      if(nodes[n].textContent.match(new RegExp(that.escapeRegExp(search),'gi'))){
        var newtextContent=nodes[n].textContent.replace(
              new RegExp(escape_regex(search),'gi'), replacement_html);
        $(nodes[n]).before(newtextContent).remove();
      }
    } else {
      replace_text(nodes[n], search, replacement_html);
    }
  }
}

function escape_regex(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

And then calling:

```
$('.highlight_terms_here').each(function(){
  replace_text(this, 
              the_word, 
              '<span style="background-color: yellow">'+the_word+'</span>');
})
```

Or simply:

```
  replace_text($('#contents')[0], the_word, 
              '<span style="background-color: yellow">'+the_word+'</span>');
```