# Javascript getElementsByTagName - include embedded elements

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I am using a fragment of javascript from the internet to collect all the `<small></small>` elements within a div id 'footnotes' and append them as an ordered list at the end of my document, with links and back links (i.e Easy HTML Footnotes), Footnotes.js:

```
var DOMsupport = document.getElementsByTagName && document.createElement;

window.onload = function() {
    if (!DOMsupport) return;

    var footNoteHolder = document.getElementById('footnotes');
    var allNotes = footNoteHolder.getElementsByTagName('small');
    var notesList = document.createElement('ol');

    notesList.className = 'notesList';

    for (var i = 0; i < allNotes.length; i++) {
        var newA = document.createElement('a');
        newA.id = 'text-' + (i + 1);
        newA.setAttribute('href', '#footnote-' + (i + 1));
        newA.setAttribute('title', 'Jump to footnote');
        newA.appendChild(document.createTextNode((i + 1)));

        newBackLink = document.createElement('a');
        newBackLink.id = 'footnote-' + (i + 1);
        newBackLink.setAttribute('href', '#text-' + (i + 1));
        newBackLink.setAttribute('title', 'Back to text');
        newBackLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode('[back]'));

        newNote = document.createElement('li');
        newNote.appendChild(document.createTextNode(allNotes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + ' '));
        newNote.appendChild(newBackLink);
        notesList.appendChild(newNote);

        allNotes[i].replaceChild(newA, allNotes[i].firstChild);
    }
    footNoteHolder.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
    footNoteHolder.appendChild(notesList);
}
```

I like the simplicity, no Jquery in sight, but I would like to be able to include line breaks `<br>` and/or links  `<a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27827297">Click for PubMed</a>` inside some of the footnotes.

When I try to include any other elements within the `<small></small>` tags the text is placed within the body - not collected and placed at the end. e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>MDT Home</title>
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' 
    src='..\..\js\footnotes.js'>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id='footnotes' ><br>

<h2>Welcome to the MDT site<br></h2><br>
I have designed the site in a minimalist style using <a href='https://www.lua.org/' title='Lua'>Lua</a> it should run on all trust machines.<br>
<br>
To use the menu click the icon at the top left. If you have a modern browser you can use keyboard shortcuts  [<small>
Alt-M: Menu.<br>
Alt-H: MDT Home.<br>
Alt-K: Hip and Knee.<br>
Alt-A: Foot and Ankle.<br>
Alt-W: Wrist and Hand.<br>
Alt-S: Shoulder and Elbow.<br>
Alt-I: Spine.<br>
Alt-C: Children.<br>
</small>] e.g move to menu by entering Alt-M.
 Please read the terms of use before proceeding to review patient data. <br>

<br></span>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if the problem lies with the selection of `allNotes` using `getElementsByTagName('small')` producing a NodeList object, or is the problem the building of the `newNote` using `allNotes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + ' '` .

Sorry I don't have the original source of this fragment any longer - normally I would credit the author - and ask them directly. In an ideal world I would learn javascript properly instead of culling fragments and pasting then into my pages.

Any help gratefully received.

Gavin

Comment: It's not all that hard to learn, and you'll benefit from the freedom to create your own code.

Comment: Judging from the code you have, and that you already know what you want to add, you should be able to add new code to fit your requirement. As David said, if you don't know how to proceed, you should spend time learning what your code is doing. Reading about [document.appendChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) is a good start.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your question is. The title leads me to believe you want to get elements by tag name, and include embedded elements when you get them, but then you're talking about adding something to footnotes. I don't see anywhere that says what the problem actually is. Please read [ask], and look into how to create a [mcve] to be placed in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spurred on by the criticism I have examined each line of this code to find why I can't have elements in my footnotes.

[It appears you can't have elements within TextNodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888198/how-do-i-get-html-tags-inside-of-a-javascript-text-node). A post which Mr Thomas is well aware of, having contributed in the comments.

I will not be learning Javascript to find an alternative mechanism of collating fragments which may or may not contain elements. I know there are good bits of Javascript, but DOM coding does not seem to be one of them.